# Página no carga nuevos datos si navego por ella pero si lo hace si actualizo manualmente

Tags: javascript, php, html

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una web con dos 3 páginas, una muestra una lista de categorías, otra muestra las entradas que hay dentro de cada categoría, y otra envía entradas a la base de datos para mostrarlo en las páginas anteriores.

El problema es el siguiente: Al rellenar el formulario y enviarlo todo va bien, miro la tabla de la bbdd y ahí esta la nueva entrada en su correspondiente tabla con todo correcto. Pero si sigo navegando por la web, voy a categorías y entro a la categoría LA NUEVA ENTRADA NO APARECE. pero si ahí actualizo esa página manualmente desde el navegador manualmente... ENTONCES SI APARECE.

Me ocurre lo mismo con un sistema de votos que he realizado. Es como si desde que entro a la web, todo lo que inserte o haga interactuando con ella, aunque si se refleje en la bbdd, no aparezca en la web hasta que actualice yo manualmente.

¿Queé parte del código necesitáis que muestre para descubrir el problema?

Archivo php que tramita el formulario:

```
<?php

    require("class/App.php");
    $app = new App();

    if(isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
        $autor = $_POST["autor"];
        $categoria = $_POST["categoria"];
        $texto = $_POST["texto"];
        $app->setEntrada($autor, $categoria, $texto);
        header("Location: gracias.php");
    }
?>
```

función de la clase que lo inserta en la BBDD

```
public function setEntrada($autor, $categoria, $texto) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO chistes (id, autor, categoria, texto, int_like, int_dislike, puntos, reportes, creado) VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?, 0, 0, 0, 0, NOW())";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $autor, $categoria, $texto);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

página común para las categorías:

```
<?php


require("class/App.php");
$app = new App();

if(isset($_GET["categoria"])){
    $categoria = $_GET["categoria"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM chistes WHERE categoria='$categoria'";
    $row_count = $app->getCountCategoria($categoria);

    if(isset($_GET["orden"])){
        switch ($_GET["orden"]) {
            case 'mejores':
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM chistes WHERE categoria='$categoria' ORDER BY int_like DESC";
                break;
            case 'peores':
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM chistes WHERE categoria='$categoria' ORDER BY puntos ASC";
                break;
            case 'fecha':
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM chistes WHERE categoria='$categoria' ORDER BY creado DESC";
                    break;
        }
    }
}




?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chistes cortos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#006EFF">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="alert alert-success guardar" role="alert">
        El chiste se ha guardado en favoritos.
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger reportar" role="alert">
        El chiste se ha reportado y será revisado.
    </div>
    <nav class="nav-superior fixed-top">
        
        <div class="nav-superior__back">
            <a onclick="window.history.back();">
                <div class="nav-superior__box-back">
                    <img class="nav-superior-back" src="images/back.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
            <div class="nav-superior__title">
                <h1 class="h4">Chistes de <?php echo $app->getTituloCategoria($categoria); ?></h1>
                
            </div>
            <img class="nav-superior__img" src="images/risa.png" alt="">
    </nav>
    <div class="index position-relative">
        
        <div class="container mt-3 mt-md-5">
            <div class="first-top"></div>
            <?php

            if($row_count > 0) {
                if($resultado = $app->con->query($sql)){
                    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                        ?>
    
                            <div data-id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" id="chiste-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="item">
                            <img src="images/heart_big.png" alt="" class="effect__heart">
                            <img src="images/caca_grande.png" alt="" class="effect__caca">
                            <p class="item__autor">Publicado por <span><?php echo $row["autor"]; ?></span></p>
                            <div class="item__chiste mb-3">
                            <?php echo nl2br($row["texto"]); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item__votos">
                                <div class="izq">
                                    <a data-id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" id="reportar-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="link-reportar">Reportar</a>
                                    <a id="guardar-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="link-guardar">Guardar</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="iconos">
                                    <div id="caca-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="caca">
                                        <img class="caca__img" src="images/caca2.png" alt="">
                                        <p><?php echo $row["int_dislike"]; ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="heart-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" class="heart">
                                        <img class="heart__img" src="images/heart.png" alt="">
                                        <p><?php echo $row["int_like"]; ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <?php
                    }
                }
    
                
            } else {
                ?>

                    <div class="item">
                        <p>Lo sentimos, actualmente no hay chistes en esta categoría.</p>
                        <p><strong>Sé el primero en <a href="enviar.php">enviar uno</a> </strong></p>
                    </div>

                <?php
            }

            ?>
            
            <div class="last-bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav-inferior container-fluid fixed-bottom d-flex text-center align-items-center ">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="images/inicio.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="categorias.php"><img src="images/categorias.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="sala-votaciones.php"><img src="images/votar.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="favoritos.php"><img src="images/favoritos.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="enviar.php"><img src="images/enviar.png" alt=""></a>
     </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *¿Queé parte del código necesitáis que muestre para descubrir el problema?* -> Qué parte del código?? No tenemos absolutamente ni idea de qué has hecho, cómo vamos a decirte nosotros qué parte necesitas mostrarnos?? Empecemos por lo básico... recargas de alguna manera la página tras realizar el insert en la BD? Porque si no obtienes los datos nuevamente es obvio que no se van a mostrar. Además te recomiendo usar el enlace [edit] y añadir *todo* lo que consideres **necesario**. No TODO, solo lo necesario por favor. Yo no puedo decirte exactamente qué parte de un código que no conozco necesito.

Comment: @Benito-B cuando envió el formulario, este se tramita en otro archivo, ahí se inserta a la BBDD y redirige por pedio de php con header() a una página de gracias. Si luego pincho en el menú de navegación a la página de categorrías, y entro en la categorçía donde añadí la nueva entrada, esta no aparece. Pero si yo manualmente le doy a actualizar la página desde el navegador, entonces si aparece.

Comment: Cómo obtienes los datos en la página de las categorías? Necesitamos ver el flujo completo. Dentro de lo posible necesitamos un [mre]. En este caso sería complicado por la base de datos, pero puedes darnos al menos lo demás. Si no tenemos que responderte intentando adivinar qué puede estar pasando y eso tan solo es una pérdida de tiempo para todos.

Comment: @Benito-B ahí puse el código que envía el formulario y la funcion que lo inserta en la bbdd, pero ahí no está el problema me parece. es como si no cargase los nuevos datos a no ser que entres directamente a la web poniendo la dirección en el navegador o si actualizas la página manualmente. navegando por ella no

Comment: Disculpa @Benito-B había pegado la página que no era, ahora si está correcta, puedes verla a ver en que estoy fallando

Comment: Puse nuevos datos... nadie tiene idea de por qué puede ser ?

Comment: Cuando dices "sigo navegando por la web" te refieres a que pinchas en un enlace que hace un `history.back()`?

Comment: @Benito-B Cuando navego por la web es que voy a otras páginas por medios de enlaces normales <a href="otra-pagina.php"> pero cuando voy a la página donde he insertado la nueva entrada, esta no aparece. solo aparece cuando estando ahí actualizo la página del navegador o con f5.

Answer (score 3):

ya encontré la solución. Era que se guardaba en caché.

Lo solucioné borrandola por medio de PHP:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 1 Jul 2000 05:00:00 GMT"); // Fecha en el pasado
```